# Problem with variable environment on netlify

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, settings, vite, netlify

I set the netlify parameters to environment variable, but it doesn't work.

Set the value in my application to this value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnQBe.png)
I also added an address to netlify
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxbP8.png)
but it's not working